# How to display Posts in wordpress page using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display Posts details in WordPress page. I have added MySQL query in WordPress page(All `Pages -> Add New Page --> Added the Code`). I am using `INSERT PHP` WordPress plugin for that.. Still it displays the error..

How to do this..?
The Code which I have used is given below...

```
[insert_php]
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_NAME","DB_PW((","DB_NAME");
$sqli="select * from cre_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id=1";
$res=mysqli_query($sqli) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo $row["object_id"];
}
[/insert_php]
```

Comment: what error are you getting? check error log.

Comment: *"Still it displays the error.."* - what error exactly is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

Firstly, you're not passing your DB connection parameter to the query.

```
$res=mysqli_query($sqli)
                  ^ missing the 1st parameter.
```

Modify it to read as:

```
$res=mysqli_query($con, $sqli)
```

and `mysqli_error()` requires DB connection be passed as a parameter

- `mysqli_error($con)`

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

However, WordPress has its own MySQL core functions. I don't know why you're using `mysql_`

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/

---

This line:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_NAME","DB_PW((","DB_NAME");
```

remove the excess brackets and the order:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","DB_USERNAME","DB_PW","DB_NAME");
```

assuming `DB_USERNAME` is a pre-defined constant that isn't showing in your question.

Syntax is:

1. host
2. username
3. password
4. database

However, constants do not get wrapped in quotes:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", DB_USERNAME, DB_PW, DB_NAME);
```

if you have in fact defined your constants.

You will need to elaborate on this, and to update your question, should my answer not provide the solution.

Consult the following regarding the use of constants:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Now it's working fine.. How to set link for each post?? whenever I am using <a href="#"> tag pt throws an error...

Comment: @NNKK you would need to post a new question, since I have answered the original post and this question should be closed and marked as solved.